# There is unexpected error, when open GPIO pin on Raspberry Pi on Java ME 8

Tags: java-me, raspberry-pi

I'm working on Raspberry Pi with Java ME 8.0 and I want to use GPIO pin 7

```
    try {
        pin = (GPIOPin) DeviceManager.open(7);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PiGPIOled.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
```

also tried with below code:

```
pin = (GPIOPin) DeviceManager.open(new GPIOPinConfig(
           0, 7, GPIOPinConfig.DIR_OUTPUT_ONLY, GPIOPinConfig.MODE_OUTPUT_PUSH_PULL,
           GPIOPinConfig.TRIGGER_BOTH_EDGES, false));
```

I have give all API permissions, But When I run  midlet I see error:
**[ERROR] [DAAPI] iso=-1:There is unexpected error, when open GPIO pin 7**

Currently I have not connected anything to GPIO 7 pin, is this is the problem?
Some of the links suggested to run usertest.sh, when i tried that I see java running and few people mentioned it worked for them wonder how ?

here is more information

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/javame8 $ ls /sys/class/gpio
export  gpio17  gpio18  gpio3  gpio7  gpiochip0  unexport
```

Thanks,
Ashok

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is I have installed midlet without #sudo and trying to run with #sudo. Installed and run midlet #sudo and it worked.